# How can I get the deep link from Facebook if user is redirected to Google Play?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, facebook-unity-sdk, deep-linking

Is it possible to get the deep link if I send a request to a user that doesn't have the app installed and Facebooks redirects him to Google Play? I want to know who invited him to play so I can reward him. Is that possible with Unity? How does this work in general? I know many games do that.

I am using the Facebook SDK for Unity and I managed to get the deep link it the user already has the app installed, but now I want to get it after he installs it from Google Play.